# Animate border moving around Material Button like circular progress indicator

Tags: android

I am wondering how I would go about making the border of my [Material Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opwz3.jpg) move like the  [Indeterminate Circular progress indicator](https://material.io/components/progress-indicators#circular-progress-indicators).

Comment: you can check [this library](https://github.com/StevenDXC/DxLoadingButton) and [this](https://github.com/nikartm/StripedProcessButton) ...

Comment: I might use this, but I was kind of looking something that would go around my buttons border. Kind of like a "snake" if that makes sense.